# How to store excel data in mysql which support simple statistics

Tags: java, mysql, excel

The scenario is, I have some excel templates in the ftp server, I need to download the excel templates and fill data into the files, then save them into mysql database.

My current solution is convert the excel file to csv, and then save the data into a text field.

But now, I need to do some simple statistic, it's not convenient to caculate the value, I need to load all rows' csv field and anylize them, then calculate the data. Is there any other store solution which support such scenario?

thanks,
allen

Comment: Are you saying you've stored a CSV file into a MySQL table as a string in a single column? The obvious solution here is to create a proper table with columns for each value, and rows for each line, then import the data into that. MySQL can do this directly with [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) if you set the table up properly.

Comment: I have done a similar project using Java which you can read at https://ezani.medium.com/creating-a-fullstack-application-with-asynchronous-ajax-html-frontend-using-jsgrid-datagrid-and-1503ec61a9cb.  There I used Apache POI for Excel fies and the OpenCSV library for CSV files. I used jsGrid and Apex charts for the grid and charting components.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks for your reply. But more templates will be added, and I don't know the schema of the excel file before, so I can't create a propery table structure. I can create the mysql table dynamically after anylizing the excel file, is there any other solution?

Comment: @Ezani thanks for your reply. I can display the file data in the frontend, I want to know how to store the data and the structure into mysql, so that I can easily do some simple calculate.

Comment: @Allen4Tech, you say you dont know the structure of the Excel sheet beforehand so I believe you may have to create the fields in the table dynamically by reading the Excel headers and creating the fields. Look for the appropriate Excel library for the programming language you are using and the rest is MySQL SQL commands e.g. CREATE TABLE...

Comment: @Ezani thanks, I have already done like this, but I want to know if there's any other solutions.